# How to convert strings containing binary/ascii mix on Python 3

Tags: python, string, byte, utf

I have a system that works in Windows with Python 2.7.  I am trying to transition to Linux and Python 3 for a specific application (the existing Windows systems will remain in use - there are many of them).  The system includes a USB-connected board with an interface that works like a serial port but isn't a serial port.  After being initialized and configured, I can send it strings consisting of command/data pairs and get responses back. In some cases, the data and the command may be non-ASCII values (>0x7F) or may be ASCII strings.  In Python 2.7, I can construct a string as something like chr(command) + ASCIIstring, send it, and it works.  When I get a string back, I can search it for key values, verify that the results are within range, etc. If I get a byte value back, such as the value of some switches or sensors, I can do ord(value) and get an integer and then I can check individual bits.

Since Python 2 doesn't have a bytes value, strings and bytes can be intermixed.  But in Python 3, if I convert using encode and decode or bytes(hex array), I either have issues sending or receiving.  If I try to convert to UTF, the codec has issues with values like 0xFF from the switches.  What I need is a way to easily convert from a Python 3 byte array that might have any value back and forth to a python 2 type string.  After a lot of frustration, I came up with the following (Windows functionality remain because I want this particular module to be OS-agnostic):

This is part of the function that reads the USB device, FD is the file descriptor for the open device.
It returns a python 2-style string

```
if LinuxFlag:
    if InWaiting(FD):
        z = os.read(FD, size)
        if Python3:
            w = ""
            for char in z: w += chr(char)
            return w
        else: return z
    else: return ""

if WinFlag:
    x, indata = win32file.ReadFile(FD, size)
    return indata
```

This is part of the function that writes to the USB device. It accepts a python 2-style string

```
if LinuxFlag:
    if Python3:
        BAlist = []
        for char in StringOfBytes: BAlist.append(ord(char))
        os.write(FD, bytes(BAlist))
    else: os.write(FD, StringOfBytes)
if WinFlag: result = win32file.WriteFile(FD, StringOfBytes)
```

That's a lengthy explanation, but here's my question: As you can see, I've found a way to loop through each byte of the incoming data and put it in a string that I can search, use ord() on, etc.  For sending, I convert the incoming string to an array of bytes, one byte at a time, and then use the bytes() function to make it something that the Python 3 write function will accept.  Is there any way to do these conversions automatically without getting codec errors or some other fault?  It almost seems that Python 3 lost the ability to mix ASCII (not UTF-8) with binary data, like that use case wasn't considered.  I can't find functions that will do these conversions in one step.  What I have works, but iterating through the entire array in both directions seems awfully clumsy.  I've seen similar questions here, but unless I'm misunderstanding something, they are all a little different from this.

Comment: If parts of the binary sequence are human-readable strings, you need to encode or decode those parts individually.

Comment: Have you tried encoding your strings as `windows-1252`? That's 8 bits, a superset of ascii, and nearly 100% full, so you're unlikely to get an error.

Comment: Your `for char in z: w += chr(char)` loop _could_ be written more compactly as a list comprehension: `''.join([chr(c) for c in z])`. Or you can decode it in one step like this: `z.decode('latin1')`. That works because Latin1 is a proper subset of Unicode. But IMHO it would be much simpler to write a separate Python 3 version that just uses `bytes` / `bytearray` rather than abusing text strings like that. Trying to do this sort of stuff in a way that works on Python 2 and Python 3 is a recipe for madness. ;)

Comment: Mark: I've got control codes, data, and ASCII strings embedded in the incoming (and outgoing) data.  So I have to parse out the command codes and non-printable data before I can convert the strings.  In Python 2, I can have a string of chars that can be parsed as needed since bytes can be chars.

Comment: Austin: It appears that windows-1252 has some missing codes like UTF-8.  I'll have to try it.  As far as I can tell, codes 129, 141, etc. are control codes.  Any idea what happens when the codec encounters them?  I know that the UTF-8 encoder doesn't like codes such as 0xFE, 0xFF, etc. which are valid values in my data stream.

Comment: PM: Tried the .join, that does work.  No idea if it's faster or slower since both are iterating over the list-of-bytes.  But I'm sure the codecs have to do the same thing.

Comment: The `z.decode('latin1')` does the same thing, I tested all 3 versions with `z = bytes(range(256))`. Using `''.join` on a list comp is more efficient than a Python loop that concatenates strings with `+`. The former is O(n) (and `.join` does its looping at C speed), the latter is O(n²) since it has to allocate a new string and copy the previous partial result on every iteration. See [Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm). `z.decode('latin1')` should be the fastest because it's also O(n) and it does it all with compiled code.

Comment: the "latin1" decode worked perfectly.  Thanks.  Wish Python had a 'binary' or 'no-translate' or 'raw' or some other decoding/encoding for serial port and control applications.  Seems silly to have to hunt for a compatible format for cases like this.  But latin1 did work.